# How to return specific Type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a method which return a "Type" among an array of GameObjects. Each GameObject got attached a component, so I'm trying this with no results.

```
private Type GetComponentOfType(string name)
{
    var component; // Error here

    for (int i = 0; i < sceneObjectsLength; i++)
    {
        component = sceneObjects[i].GetComponent(Type.GetType(name));
    }

    return component;
}
```

---

An example to show what's the idea:

```
private Start()
{
    Circle circle:
    circle = GetComponentOfType("Circle");
    Debug.Log(circle.Radius());

    Square square;
    square = GetComponentOfType("Square");
    Debug.Log(square.Sides());
}
```

Comment: Generics. Look them up.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I'm trying this which no results"_?

Comment: Are you hardcoding `"Circle"` or is it read as a string somewhere? If it's hardcoded, just use generics.

Comment: Or, set some ninject factory, which will give you needed instance of needed type: `ninjectKernel.Get<MyType>()`

Comment: @Flydog57 it was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Type` object contains information about a type. It is not the type itself. You want to use generics

```
private T GetComponent<T>()
    where T : Component
{
    T component;

    for (int i = 0; i < sceneObjectsLength; i++)
    {
        component = (T)sceneObjects[i].GetComponent(typeof(T));
    }

    return component;
}
```

You can call it with:

```
Circle circle = GetComponent<Circle>();
```

However, you have a locial problem. `return` does only return a single component, but you try to get several components in a loop. If your intention was to return the first component of this type, then you should write

```
private T GetComponent<T>()
    where T : Component
{
    return sceneObjects
        .Select(obj => obj.GetComponent(typeof(T)))
        .Where(obj => obj != null)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can get all objects of a type from all game objects with

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetComponents<T>()
    where T : Component
{
    return sceneObjects
        .SelectMany(obj => obj.GetComponents<T>());
}
```

---

You got an error in `var component;` because `var` can only be used if the compiler can infer the type as in `var component = new Circle();`. Here `var` is inferred to be `Circle`. `var` is not like a Basic `Variant` type that can accept a value of any type. It just prevents you of writing the type name twice as in `Circle component = new Circle();`

Comment: `T` won't be a subclass of `GameObject`, it will be a subclass of `Component`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the first one work pretty well, luckily there is only component of its kind, I tried the other ones but I got an error: 

Cannot implicity convert type 'System.collection.generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.Component>' to 'System.IEquatable<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Did you write `private IEquatable<T> GetComponents<T>()` instead of `private IEnumerable<T> GetComponents<T>()`?